# String compatible equivalent of Excel Small()/ Large()/ Rank()

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm wondering if there is a string version of the Excel Small()/ Large()/ Rank() functions, i.e. a function that could look at a list of strings and tell you how they rank.

E.g. in the following example, I have the list on the left and I think I'd like a function that could return the values on the right, or some variant thereof.

```
John        4
            1
David       2
            1
Yeme        5
            1
Gretchen    3
```

Ideally it would handle blank entries somehow, as shown without just totally failing.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, you want to sort alphabetically? Or sort each name based on the right hand values in order?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),1,COUNTIF($a$2:$a$8,"<"&a2)+2)
```

This counts how many names are "less than" than this name.  Since it can't really compare to blank cells, this forces blanks as rank 1, and offsets everything by 2 (1 for blank, and 1 to start counting at 1 instead of zero).

Comment: I can see where you're heading with this, and it sort of works, for me your formula ranks "David" and "Gretchen" at the same level for some reason.

Comment: Couple small errors...  I was missing a $, so the range was moving down.  2nd, I suppose it should end at A8, not A7 (but should be adjusted for your data anyway).  I've fixed both in answer.